# Unity Integer Array Access Problem

Tags: unity, c#

I am beginner to Unity and need some help about the code below. I want to pass the array with into second script. But I got only **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** What is the problem with the code ?

---- First Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayableCells : MonoBehaviour {


    public static PlayableCells Instance;

    public int[][] moves;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public int[] PossibleMoves(int cell_id) {

        int[] cell_0 = new int[] {2, 11, 20};
        int[] cell_1 = new int[] {3, 10, 12, 21};
        int[] cell_2 = new int[] {0, 4, 11, 13, 22};
        int[] cell_3 = new int[] {1, 5, 12, 14, 23};
        int[] cell_4 = new int[] {2, 6, 13, 15, 24};
        int[] cell_5 = new int[] {3, 7, 14, 16, 25};
        int[] cell_6 = new int[] {4, 8, 15, 17, 26};
        int[] cell_7 = new int[] {5, 9, 16, 18, 27};
        int[] cell_8 = new int[] {6, 17, 19, 28};
        int[] cell_9 = new int[] {7, 18, 29};

        int [][] moves = {
            cell_0,
            cell_1,
            cell_2,
            cell_3,
            cell_4,
            cell_5,
            cell_6,
            cell_7,
            cell_8,
            cell_9

        };

        return moves [cell_id];
    }

    void Awake(){
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

-----Second Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Cell : MonoBehaviour {

    public int cell_id;
    public int[] pscell;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        SetCell();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update () {

    }

    void SetCell() {
        string btnName = this.gameObject.name;
        cell_id = Int32.Parse(btnName.Substring(btnName.LastIndexOf('_') + 1));
        pscell = PlayableCells.Instance.PossibleMoves (cell_id);

    }

    public void TaskOnClick()
    {   

        GameController.Instance.checkMove(cell_id,pscell);
        int score = GameController.Instance.getScore();
        this.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "" + score;


    }


}
```